# Rails: How to add helper to do filters in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am using custom filter with autocomplete feature in active admin and i have done this.

```
filter :user_id_eq,
    as: :string,
    input_html: {
      class: 'autocomplete',
      id: 'user_id',
      display_name: '',
      data: {
        url: '/admin/autocomplete/users',
      },
    }
    label: 'User'
```

I have done above code from [here](https://gist.github.com/tylerhunt/8058321)

so my problem is how can i use new helper function `user_auto_complete` that will take the symbol and the label as arguments, and then generate this filter output.